# Angular routerLink and Router.Navigate behaving differently

Tags: angular, angular5

I have the code in App Routing Module as follows.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo:'Person/AllPersons', pathMatch:'full'  },
    { path: 'Person/AllPersons', component: AllPersonsComponent },
    { path: 'Person/AddPerson', component: AddPersonComponent },
    { path: 'Teacher/AllTeachers', component: AllTeachersComponent },
    { path: 'Teacher/AddTeacher', component: AddTeacherComponent }

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Now in AllPersonsComponent.html I have the following code.

```
<a routerLink="Teacher/AddTeacher">Add Teacher</a>
```

Now when I click on it. It's not redirecting to AddTeacher Component. Instead it is populating an error as follows
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Person/AllPersons/Teacher/AddTeacher'.

But when I do like this it is redirecting to Correct path.

```
<a (click)="Func()">Add Teacher</a>
```

And in .ts file as follows.

```
Func() {
    this.router.navigate(['Teacher/AddTeacher']);
  }
```

Then it is navigating to Add Teacher component. Can any one help me with this as of why routerLink is failing and how to achieve it through routerLink?

Comment: Tried <a [routerLink]="['Teacher/AddTeacher']"> ?

Comment: Yes @rrd. I have tried it. Still it isn't working. Getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your routerLink should start with forwardslash 
(Add Teacher)

According to angular documentation

If the first segment begins with /, the router will look up the route from the root of the app.

so if u added (/) at the beginning your link will render after starting with your - domain/Teacher/AddTeacher

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Teacher/AddTeacher']">Add Teacher</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

i see that you declared your routes in wrong way first of all you should have 2 separed routes for `Person` and `Teacher` and other routes related to `Person` or `Teacher` should be childroutes, and one more error here, you should declare all routes in lowercase, so solution to your promblem should look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo:'person/all-person', pathMatch:'full'  },
    { path: 'person', component: PersonComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'all-persons', component: AllPersonComponent},
          { path: 'add-person', component: AddPersonComponent}
        ]
    },
    { path: 'teacher', component: PersonComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'all-teachers', component: AllTeacherComponent},
          { path: 'add-teacher', component: AddTeacherComponent}
        ]
    },

  }

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Or you can have a simple routes `person` and `person/:page-type` and you can have one component for this and in `ngOnInit` you can have something like this

```
showAllPersonTemplate = false;
showAddPersonTemplate = false;

ngOnInit(){
 const pageType = this.router.params
  let pageType = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('page-type'); 

  // and here you verify what route user navigate
  if(pageType === 'add-person' ) {
   this.showAddPersonTemplate  = true;
  }

  if(pageType === 'all-person' ) {
   this.showAllPersonTemplate = true;
  }

  // And based on routes params you show or hide different html
}
```

Read more information on angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/router